Draw straight-line diagram or single-line graph using Highcharts
I would like to use Highcharts (or similar) to display road attribute data as a straight-line diagram or single-line graph, but I can't find any examples that would be easy for this non-programmer to adapt. Is it possible to display linear referenced data on a single line using multiple colors using openly available chart-making software?
What I would like to accomplish:

Ex. data that will be queried from a database by road id/(range of ids):



road_id
mp_start
mp_end
surftype
sidewalks




1
0
2
1
1


1
2
4
1
1


1
4
5
2
1


1
5
10
3
0



An example I have found which gives me hope this is possible:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944221/how-to-draw-single-line-graph-using-highcharts
Additional wants: I would like to show multiple attributes like: surface type, sidewalks present, shoulder type etc. This would require multiple lines/color legends for each attribute for a given road id on the same page/graph/chart/frame with all lines sharing the same x-axis. It would be ideal if these lines could pan and zoom in-sync.

HighCharts is an Interactive Charting Library - not GIS migrating this post.

I found a nice example of stacking bar charts here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54667383/highcharts-stacked-bar-chart-for-multiple-bars I could adapt to my needs.
https://jsfiddle.net/g7ys8ahz/
